# How to release a variable using automatic reference counting? I do not want to set something to nil since it will create dangling pointers?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

How to release anything while using arc? I do not want to set something to nil since it will create dangling pointers?

Comment: _Rather than having to think about about retain and release operations, ARC allows you to concentrate on the interesting code..._ - Read first 2 sentences her - [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: You do not have to release anything ARC takes care of itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to -- can't -- release anything when using ARC. The closest equivalent is, as you suggest, setting the variable to `nil`, but it's not strictly necessary. It won't create dangling pointers.

Comment: If I am setting a variable to nil, the variable is now nil, but the memory for the object it used to point to is still allocated, so in short I am creating a dangling pointer.What if I want to that for eg.[objArray addObject:item];
            item=nil;any substitue code for this situation.